# Kafka is sending same event twice to different instances of micro service

Tags: apache-kafka

We have 2 kafka cluster each with 6 nodes active and standby. And a topic with 12 partions and 12 instances of app is running. Our app is a consumer and all consumers use same consumer group ID to receive events from kafka. Event processing from kafka is sequential which is 'event comes in-> process the event->do manual ack'. This event processing takes approx 5 seconds to complete and do manual acknowledge. Though, they are multiple instances only one event at a time will be processed. But, recently we found an issue in production that consumer re balancing is happening for every 2 seconds and due to this message offset commit(manual ack) is being failed and same event is being sent twice and resulting in duplicate record insertion in database.

```
Kafka consume config values are:

max.poll.interval.ms = 300000//5 mins
max.poll.records = 500
heartbeat.interval.ms=3000
session.timeout.ms=10000
```

Errors seen:

1. commit offset failed since the consumer is not part of active group.
   2.Time between subsequent calls to poll() was longer than configured  max poll       interval milli seconds which typically implies that poll loop is spending too much of time message processing.

but message processing is taking 5 seconds not more than configured max poll interval which is 5 mins. As it is sequential processing, only one consumer can poll and get event at once and other instances had to wait till their turn to poll, is it causing above 2 errors and  rebalancing? Appreciate the help.

Comment: A single event takes 5 seconds? You're polling 500 records at a time. That's 2500 seconds between polls, or about 42 minutes. Regarding duplicates, are you not using a transactional producer and enabling read isolation on consumers? For your database writing, are you not using Kafka Connect?

Comment: Single record each time, not 500 records. We are not using kafka connect.not sure about transactional producer and enabling read isolation.

Comment: It would help :  1. is it batch interface or single record at a time, if it is single record - why the "max.poll.records = 500" ? 2. what is request.timeout.ms configured -- if there are no poll called between the request.timeout.ms configured, would lead to consumer rebalance 3. also adding batch interface and parallel streaming the records would speed up - 4. we had a similar scenario with many downstream dependencies, so we wrote/offloaded record to aws kinesis and lambda to process( giving a design alternative)

Comment: You have `max.poll.records=500`, and it's not very clear how you're calculating the time. Kafka Connect would definitely be recommended here, as it handles these failures better. And for transactions or exactly once processing see https://www.confluent.io/blog/exactly-once-semantics-are-possible-heres-how-apache-kafka-does-it/

Comment: It is not a batch processing. For each poll, it is a single record at a time. And the request.timoue.ms was configured as 30000(30 secs).

Comment: So, as per max.poll.records and max.poll.interval.ms, kafka is expecting 500 records within above mentioned max.poll.interval.ms? My understanding with these 2 configurations are, maximum of 500 records in each poll within max poll interval time. Please let me know exactly what these configurations means?

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs - has documentation for the kafka consumer configurations